# 2 ceiling fans. 1 dims fully and other doesnt dim enough

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I had 2 ceiling fans installed in kids rooms. Same exact fan in both rooms. 2 switches control them. One on off for the fan. And one dimmer switch for the lights. One fan works perfect amd the lights dim down to almost off like 95% off. The other fan lights dim down to about only 75% off. How can i get the other lights to dim more? Same exact fans, bulbs, wiring and switches in the wall.

Comment: Do your dimmers have a *low-end trim* setting on them?

Comment: No, there's no settings. Just wires out the back and a single slider to turn on and dim. I had the same exact dimmers at my old house and they worked fine there.

Comment: What make and model are said dimmers?

Comment: Believe its Leviton 6672-1LW SureSlide Universal 150W LED/CFL. They dont sell that exact one anymore at home depot but this is it on ebay https://www.ebay.com/p/1310437153?iid=233513242030&chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=233513242030&targetid=883115548502&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9005550&poi=&campaignid=6470049731&mkgroupid=84221218450&rlsatarget=pla-883115548502&abcId=1141176&merchantid=6296724&gclid=Cj0KCQjwncT1BRDhARIsAOQF9Ln2RJUWBGzohzOH882CFdxvzH4ChX8iYk9uPX0Ik9lpgp8yANOiPHQaAnEaEALw_wcB